# predicting admission rate using gre in linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

I am learning linear regression and I am trying to make a simple linear regression program in Jupyter notebook in python, I am using the data from kaggle here is the link
https://www.kaggle.com/mohansacharya/graduate-admissions
to predict the relationship between GRE score and the chance of admission, but I keep on getting a negative slope, even if its a positive correlation

this is the code that I am executing

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.0, 9.0)

# Preprocessing Input data
data = pd.read_csv('gre.csv')
X = data.iloc[:, 1]
Y = data.iloc[:, 8]
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.xlabel('GRE score')
plt.ylabel('Chance of getting into university %')
plt.show()

m = 0
c = 0

L = 0.0001  # The learning Rate
epochs = 10000  # The number of iterations to perform gradient descent

n = float(len(X)) # Number of elements in X

# Performing Gradient Descent 
for i in range(epochs): 
    Y_pred = m*X + c  # The current predicted value of Y
    D_m = (-2/n) * sum(X * (Y - Y_pred))  # Derivative wrt m
    D_c = (-2/n) * sum(Y - Y_pred)  # Derivative wrt c
    m = m - L * D_m  # Update m
    c = c - L * D_c  # Update c
    
print (m, c)
```

when I print m and c I get 'nan' and 'nan' as output, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the learning rate. If you decrease the learning rate you can get an okayish fit.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.0, 9.0)

# Preprocessing Input data
data = pd.read_csv('gre.csv')
X = data.iloc[:, 1]
Y = data.iloc[:, 8]

m = 0
c = 0
L = 0.0000001  # The learning Rate
epochs = 100  # The number of iterations to perform gradient descent
n = float(len(X))  # Number of elements in X

# Performing Gradient Descent
for i in range(epochs):    
    Y_pred = m*X + c  # The current predicted value of Y
    D_m = (-2/n) * sum(X * (Y - Y_pred))  # Derivative wrt m
    D_c = (-2/n) * sum(Y - Y_pred)  # Derivative wrt c
    m = m - L * D_m  # Update m
    c = c - L * D_c  # Update c    

print("Slope, Intercept:", m, c)

plt.xlabel('GRE score')
plt.ylabel('Chance of getting into university %')
axes = plt.gca()
Y_preds = c + m * X
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.plot(X, Y_preds, '--')
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
Slope, Intercept: 0.0019885000304672488 6.212311206699001e-06
```

[image]

If you use `scikit-learn` implementation you get a better fit. As it uses `normalization` and `Least Squares Estimates` method rather than gradient descent.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

data = pd.read_csv('gre.csv')

X, y = data.iloc[:, 1], data.iloc[:, 8].values
X = X.values.reshape(-1, 1)

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X, y)

y_pred = regr.predict(X)

# The coefficients
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)

# The mean squared error
print('Mean squared error: %.2f' % mean_squared_error(y, y_pred))

# The coefficient of determination: 1 is perfect prediction
print('Coefficient of determination: %.2f' % r2_score(y, y_pred))

# Plot outputs
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.0, 9.0)
plt.xlabel('GRE score')
plt.ylabel('Chance of getting into university %')
plt.scatter(X, y,  color='black')
plt.plot(X, y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

Output:

```
Coefficients: 
 [0.01012587]
Mean squared error: 0.01
Coefficient of determination: 0.66
```

[image]